# getProperty() become slower and slower in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

My goal is to iterate through all relationships of a node and print out one particular property of each relationship. My node has a lot of relationships (a few hundred thousands). My iteration goes slower and slower in the iteration loop. Could someone make any suggestion or comments on my code? Thank you in advanced!

```
    Node _node = sHelper.getNodeById(id);
    if (_node != null) {
        try (Transaction tx = graphDB.beginTx()) {
            if (_node.hasProperty("PublicKey")) {
                try {

                    double coin = 0;

                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./"+id+"_balance.txt"));

                    //Iterator<Relationship> rels = _node.getRelationships(Direction.INCOMING).iterator();
                    int kk = 0;
                    for(Relationship rel : _node.getRelationships(Direction.INCOMING)){
                        //Relationship rel = rels.next();

                        coin = (double) rel.getProperty("Bitcoin");

                        if((kk++)%10000==0){
                        System.out.println(appr+"\t"+coin);
                        }
                    }
                    kk=0;
                    //rels = _node.getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING).iterator();
                    for(Relationship rel : _node.getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING)){
                        //Relationship rel = rels.next();

                        coin = (double) rel.getProperty("Bitcoin");

                        if((kk++)%10000==0){
                        System.out.println(coin);
                        }
                    }

                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {


            }
            tx.success();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("INVALID NODE ID!");
    }
```

Comment: Could you let us know what you are trying to achieve? I believe that the traversal API is faster than Cypher, but you may be able to achieve what you are looking for quite easily with a query, either aggregating or paging the results.

Comment: For each relationship in my graph, I also have a timestamp which represents how many bitcoins sent or received. What I want to achieve is to plot the daily balance of this node.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to plot the daily balance then you do not need to retrieve all of the relationships that there ever have been. I will answer in Cypher as it is all that I know:

Sum of transactions on a given day:

```
MATCH (a:Address) WHERE ID(a) = 12345
MATCH (a)-[s:SENT]->()
WHERE s.timestamp >= tsStartOfDay AND s.timestamp <= tsEndOfDay
WITH a, SUM(s.coin) as sent
MATCH (a)<-[r:RECEIVE]-()
WHERE r.timestamp >= tsStartOfDay AND r.timestamp <= tsEndOfDay
RETURN SUM(r.coin) - sent
```

I've assumed the label `Address` for your Send/Request key and relationship types of `SENT` and `RECEIVE`. tsStartOfDay and tsEndOfDay are assumed to be parameters passed to the query which represent the long value timestamp for the day you are summing values for.

You might consider storing the balance on the node as each send/receive is enacted so that no calculation is needed. So that each time a new transaction is added to your system it updates the property:

```
MATCH (a:Address) WHERE ID(a) = 12345
CREATE a<-[:RECEIVE{coin:0.01}]-(howeverYouModelFromNode)
SET a.balance = a.balance + 0.01
```

If you have already modelled lots of data without the running total you could run a query to add it to each of your Address nodes based off all the existing data. I assume that you then consolidate all these values into a total for a wallet or account for which you can then just sum the balance properties of each Address node.

NOTE: Be careful storing values in a double precision variable, you might get rounding errors especially when dealing with the fractional nature of Bitcoin currency.